# if line contains contains pattern A do smth with following lines until line cointains pattern B & nodeJS

Tags: node.js, text-parsing, string-parsing

I'm processing through Telegram history (txt file) reading it line by line  when I when there is a  pattern

```
 Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:* / * (*)
```

example

```
 Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:GAS / BTC (binance)
```

then store "following lines" in a separate variables each (and also store that that traiding pair RDN/ BTC and exchange bittrex) in separate variables) until it hits timestamp (today's date), then search for the pattern again

but when I see pattern

```
 Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:TARGET
```

proceed to next line

whole example

```
Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:IOC/ BTC (bittrex)

BUY :  0.00164

SELL :

TARGET 1 : 0.00180
TARGET 2 : 0.00205
TARGET 3 : 0.00240

STOP LOS : 0.000120
2018-04-19 15:46:57 Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals:TARGET
```

I've got some incomplete pseudocode but it is mostly BS anyway - quite new to parsing text aynway here is

```
    let now = new Date();

// var diff = (now.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 60000; // diff in min
  const fs = require('fs'),
      path = require('path'),
      filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'chats.txt'),
      // myString = "Free_Trade_Calls__AltSignals";
      buy,
      sell = [3],
      sl;
  let lines = []; 

  const buf = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
  lines [] = buf.toString().split('\n'){
    for (line < lines.length){
      if (!err) {
        if(line.indexOf("Trade_Calls__AltSignals: * / * (*)") > -1) {
          currency = line.indexOf(2);
          exchange = line.indexOf(4);
          nextline();
          while (line.indexOf($new.Date) < - 1){ // no containing Date
            if (line.indexOf(buy) > -1 ){
              line = buy
            }
            if (line.indexOf(buy) > -1 ){

          }
       }else{
         nextline();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: 1) indexOf does string match 2) regex in JS has to be in `/<your regex here>/` 3) Star symbol marks repetition not <anything goes here>.

Comment: `lines [] = buf.toString().split('\n'){` is not JavaScript, maybe try using a language you're more familiar with